# Loop object to create AND operator with javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to filter through an object like this if I the number of `filterparameters`  is unknown or if even if it contains any keys and values. I am thinking to loop through `filterparameters` first and then building a AND operator. What's the best solution for this problem?

```
var filterParameters = {color: "red", size: "small"};
var jsonFiltered = $.grep(json, function (j) {
    return (j.color === filterParameters.color) && (j.size === filterParameters.size)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxjLhoqo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your filter parameters, using the `key` to check it's value against that in the current iteration of `json`:

```
var filterParameters = {color: "red", size: "small"};
var jsonFiltered = $.grep(json, function (j) {
    filter = true;
    $.each(filterParameters, function(i, v){
        filter = j[i] != v ? false : filter
    });
    return filter;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxjLhoqo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate. keys returns all properties of your object as a new array.

```
var keys = Object.keys(filterParameters);
keys.length --> 2
keys[0] ---> "color"

for(i=0;len=keys.length;i<len;i++){
   //filterParameters[keys[i]] do some processing here.
}
```

P.S: this won't work on IE < 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `every` together with `Object.keys`:

```
var where = function(obj, xs) {
  return xs.filter(function(x) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function(k) {
      return obj[k] === x[k];
    });
  });
};

var jsonFiltered = where(filterParameters, json);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pxjLhoqo/2/